# why the break statement doesn't break from while loop?

Tags: java, while-loop, break

why doesn't this code segment break from the while loop ? (see code down below) :
what i expected is that when i type the word "end" the while loop breaks.
but it doesn't.

```
if(element=="end")
{
    break;
}
```

here is the java class i used:

```
public class Something {
        
    private List<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    private static BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    
    /**
     * the method "fillList" fills an ArrayList with a certain number of items (this number is defined in the parameter) 
     * the method "deleteList" deletes the selected items (selected using BufferedReader.readline() ) from the ArrayList 
     * until you enter the word "end", which breaks from the loop
    */
    public void fillList(int nbElements)
    {
        System.out.println("you are going to append "+nbElements+" Elements" );
        for(int i=0;i<nbElements;i++)
        {           
            System.out.println("insert element N° "+(i+1) );
            try 
            {
                String element = br.readLine();
                this.aList.add(element);
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                System.out.println("an error occured");
            }                       
        }   
    }
        
    public void deleteList() 
    {       
        while(true)
        {       
            System.out.println("choose the item to delete");                                            
            try 
            {
                String element = br.readLine();
                if(element=="end")
                {
                    break;
                }
                this.aList.remove(element);
                this.displayList();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {           
                System.out.println("an error occured");
            }           
        }
    }
    
    
    public void displayList()
    { 
        System.out.println(this.aList);
    }
}
```

in the main method (inside another class not shown here), i called the methods "fillList" then "displayList" and then "deleteList"

Comment: There is no `while` loop, it's a `for` loop.  There's no `break` statement in the loop.  You really should show the actual code you are having issues with, your example is pretty terrible and I'm having a hard time understanding what the problem actually is.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `element == "end"` with`element.equals("end")`